# I'm need an API(java) or Tools to get Zabbix Graphs requesting remote server ? Regards

Tags: zabbix

I'm need an API(java) or Tools to get Zabbix Graphs requesting remote server ?
Is it possible to integrate Zabbix to others tools like (grafana,graphite)
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Zabbix API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api) does not support retrieving graphs at this time.

As for Grafana integration, [it is possible](https://github.com/alexanderzobnin/grafana-zabbix) - but that's a different topic, and it's probably best to keep one question for one topic.

Comment: Richlv Thanks for your reply :)